# Image export artboard size is wrong figma typescript

Tags: typescript, figma

I was trying to use a github based project https://github.com/naftalibeder/figma-frame-exporter

Inside main.ts, you can see that,

```
else if (node.type === "FRAME" || node.type === "COMPONENT" || node.type === "GROUP") {
      exportables.push({
        id: node.id,
        parentName: node.name,
        variants: [],
        size: {
          width: node.width, //////////////I WISH to give a fixed width
          height: node.height,/////////////I WISH to give a fixed height
        },
      });
    }
```

and it is returning to the UI as below in this function

```
const generateExport = async (config: Config) => {
  const exportables = getExportables();
  const exportPayload = await getExportPayload(exportables, config, { isFinal: true });

  figma.ui.postMessage({
    type: "EXPORT",
    exportPayload,
  });
};
```

In the UI,
the size attribute is still undefined.